# Where best to register Angular 2 providers

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-decorators

I wrote three services for an Angular 2 app, with the configuration that two are injected into the third and used there. After importing the two (all three decorated with `@Injectable()`), I still received an unknown provider error.

To solve it I attempted to place the injected services into the modules providers array, which worked.  Is this the best approach?

Angular documentation shows listing injectables at the component level. Can I just place all injectables into the modules providers array?

Seems like this would simplify application setup as everything is configured in a central location for each module.  No searching for dependencies on a component by component basis.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, put it in the `@NgModule.providers` if the service is to be application scoped (singleton). Only add it to the `@Component.providers` if the service should be component scoped<sup>**1**</sup> (each component should get its own instance)

---

<sub>**1** - See also [Hierarchical Injectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**It depends upon your requirement that what kind of service you want.**
**Singleton service**
If you want to use **`singleton service`**, you can place your service somewhere in central area. You will think you should use/place service in **`AppModule`**. 
But still to achieve true singleton pattern/instance you should place/declare service in **[CoreModule-please check how to user CoreModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-module)** and then import **`CoreModule`** to **`AppModule`**.

**Multiple Instance service**

If you declare serivce in **`@Component decorator`** of the components,  you will have different instances of the service in different components.